# Publishing a post with a picture to the facebook page with restFb

Tags: java, facebook, image, publish, restfb

When I publish a picture to my wall by

```
FacebookType publish = fc.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
                      BinaryAttachment.with(attachmentName, temporaryStream),
                      Parameter.with("message", "my myssage"));
```

the post is created as expected. I can see a message and the published pictute under the message .

but when I want to do the same but on some pages wall instead the user wall by.

```
FacebookType publish = fc.publish(pageId + "/photos", FacebookType.class,
                      BinaryAttachment.with(attachmentName, temporaryStream),
                      Parameter.with("message", "my myssage"));
```

the post is published, but I can see only text. Not the picture. The picture can be seen only when I click on the date of the post. I can also reach this photo by clicking on the photos on the top of the page and then "name of the page" photos tab.

Is there any way how to see the photo as the part of the post also when I post it on a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution. To publish post with a photo to the section with normal "text only" posts you need publish a photo to your wall (your user wall not the wall of the page), then get its link and finally create a feed to the page with the the picture link.

here is the sample code:

```
FacebookType photo = fc.publish(pageid + "/photos" , FacebookType.class,
            BinaryAttachment.with(photoName, photoInputStream));
Link photoLink = fc.fetchObject(photo.getId(), Link.class);
FacebookType post =  fc.publish(pageid + "/feed", FacebookType.class,
            Parameter.with("message", "your message"),Parameter.with("type", "photo"),
            Parameter.with("link", photoLink.getLink()));
```

edit: I forgot about one thing. When you later delete the post, you do not delete to photo. To do that you have to do that manually.

Answer (score 3):

Your Answer worked a treat and helped me untold amounts however i found with my solution I didn't need

```
FacebookType post =  fc.publish(pageid + "/feed", FacebookType.class,
        Parameter.with("message", "your message"),Parameter.with("type", "photo"),
        Parameter.with("link", photoLink.getLink()));
```

as i would recive an error (that i should have copied to show you) but `photoLink.getLink()` returned null in my case.

so my updated solution ended up being

```
        FacebookType photo = client.publish(groupId + "/photos",
            FacebookType.class,
            BinaryAttachment.with(imageName), 
                    imageAsBytes, 
                    "image/png"), 
            Parameter.with("message", 
                    message));
```

Just my 2 cents, Thanks again for your help!

**EDIT**

Also while playing around I noticed that in the solution I arrived at I was creating a `FacebookType photo` object and this object doesn't get used anywhere, your just calling the publish method of the client that's created further up in your program.

my final class is below, (my application is taking an image from the computer and posing to a groups wall)

```
    public void createImagePostInGroup(String message, String groupId, String imageFilePath){

    byte[] imageAsBytes = fetchBytesFromImage(imageFilePath);

    DefaultFacebookClient client =
        new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.LATEST);

    client.publish(groupId + "/photos",
            FacebookType.class,
            BinaryAttachment.with(imageFilePath.substring(imageFilePath.length()-34), 
                    imageAsBytes, 
                    "image/png"), 
            Parameter.with("message", 
                    message));
}
```

And my image is converted into a byte array in this method

```
private byte[] fetchBytesFromImage(String imageFile) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte fileContent[] = null;

    try{

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFile));

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
        baos.flush();
        fileContent = baos.toByteArray();

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  fileContent;

}
```

Again thanks for your help.